# CSS transform not updating with jQuery in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to translate an element on the `input` event of an html range input slider. But when I inspect the element, the inline styles created by jQuery aren't updating, but ONLY on the transform. I have applied some dummy styles just to make sure the css is being updated at all, and they are. Everything else updates exactly as expected.

It *almost* works one time if the item hasn't been transformed yet. But after a CSS transform is applied, it doesn't update. I've tested in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox with the same result.

### Here's the method:

```
useInputValues : function(){
    $('input[id$="-x"]').on('input', function(e){
        var id = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-item-id'),
            item = $('.grid [data-item-id="' + id + '"]'),
            x = $(this).val(),
            y = $(item).css('transform').split(',')[5] || 0,
            trans = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
            console.log(x + ", " + y); // this shows the values are correct and updating properly       

        // translate the element. Why doesn't this update each time?
        $(item).css('transform', trans); 

        // update the position attribute
        $(item).attr('data-x', x); // this happily updates in real time as expected
    })
},
```

### Further context: Working without jQuery

I am using the [interact.js](http://interactjs.io/) script so that the item can be dragged around for the same effect. The function it uses is very similar to mine, but it updates properly (without jQuery).

```
resizeMove : function(event){
    var target = event.target,
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);
    target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    // Notice here: same general idea, but it's working
    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    this.updateInputValues(target);
},
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

## Edit: Fiddle

See it doing the same thing here: https://jsfiddle.net/d5kdmp0v/1/

Comment: Hm, that's hard to debug - can you create a minimal example showing the problem, e.g. using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Thanks, Cedric ... I added a fiddle above. If you inspect the element, you can watch the data-x attribute being updated while the transform does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the value of the `transform` style will return a matrix something like the following:

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

Because you are splitting this string on a comma, you still have a bracket in the string of the 6th element of the result, so the string is `0)`. That's an invalid CSS value.

If you remove that bracket before doing your split, you get what you're expecting:

```
y = $(item).css('transform').replace(')', '').split(',')[5] || 0
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d5kdmp0v/2/)

Comment: That did it! I knew it was something simple, but I just couldn't see it! Many thanks.

Comment: @BarryT.Smith Glad to have helped.